# How use Long type for Skip in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

How I can use long type (Int64) with Skip in Linq. It support only Int32.

```
dataContext.Persons.Skip(LongNumber);
```

Comment: Does your `Persons` collection *have* more than 2 billion rows? (`LongCount` supports this, but very few other operations do.)

Comment: Even if they exist, you should never have to skip that many records, not even anywhere close to int.MaxValue. With large numbers of records, Skip/Take without proper filtering/ordering doesn't make sense. So it's good the overload wasn't implemented.

Comment: I agree. With skip I must implemented where filter. So skip will never be bigger than Int32.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a while loop:

```
// Some init
List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
List<Person> resultList = persons;
long bigNumber = 3 * (long)int.MaxValue + 12;

while (bigNumber > int.MaxValue)
{
    resultList = resultList.Skip(int.MaxValue).ToList();
    bigNumber -= int.MaxValue;
}
resultList = resultList.Skip(int.MaxValue).ToList();
// Then what do what you want with this result list
```

But does your collection have more than `int.MaxValue` entries?

Comment: As Gert Arnold write, I must impemented where filter. So skip will never be  bigger than Int32.

Comment: This is a good workaround for a normal list, but many Linq providers will fail using this method unfortunately. Entity Framework for example will not work as it keeps an internal track of the skip count as an `int`.

Comment: Actually, I'd revise that comment and say this is an awful method to use for Entity Framework as it's using `ToList()` which would potentially being billions of records into memory - please don't do that!

Answer (score 4):

The following extension method `BigSkip` allows skipping more than the `Int32.MaxValue` maximum value of LINQ's `Skip` method by calling the method multiple times until the long value has been reached. This method has the advantage of not causing iteration over the collection prematurely.

example usage

```
bigCollection.BigSkip(howMany: int.MaxValue + 1l)
```

method

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

static public class LinqExtensions
{
    static public IEnumerable<T> BigSkip<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, long howMany)
        => BigSkip(items, Int32.MaxValue, howMany);

    internal static IEnumerable<T> BigSkip<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, int segmentSize, long howMany)
    {
        long segmentCount = Math.DivRem(howMany, segmentSize,
            out long remainder);

        for (long i = 0; i < segmentCount; i += 1)
            items = items.Skip(segmentSize);

        if (remainder != 0)
            items = items.Skip((int)remainder);

        return items;
    }

}
```

The method has been split into two: the `internal` overload is for convenience allowing a smaller segment size to be specified than `Int32.MaxValue` to make it unit testable on a smaller scale.

bonus

Replace `Skip` with `Take` to make a `BigTake` method; this same extension method pattern can be used to extend the reach of other LINQ methods.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an implementation that includes a fast path, in case the `count` is in the `Int32` range. In that case, any optimizations that are embedded in the native [`Skip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skip) implementation are enabled.

```
/// <summary>Bypasses a specified number of elements in a sequence and then
/// returns the remaining elements.</summary>
public static IEnumerable<T> LongSkip<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, long count)
{
    if (count >= 0 && count <= Int32.MaxValue)
        return source.Skip(checked((int)count));
    else
        return Iterator(source, count);

    static IEnumerable<T> Iterator(IEnumerable<T> source, long count)
    {
        long current = 0;
        foreach (var item in source)
            if (++current > count) yield return item;
    }
}
```