# Entity Framework Skip with Int64 parameter

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I don't get why

```
Int64 Id=10; 
int take=100;
var result =  db.Cars.OrderBy(x => x.Id).Skip(Id).Take(take).ToList();
```

does not compile, however

```
int Id=10; 
int take=100;
var result =  db.Cars.OrderBy(x => x.Id).Skip(Id).Take(take).ToList();
```

compiles successfully.
How can one work with an Int64 as a parameter for .Skip() without the potential losses that could arise from a cast?

Comment: The LINQ `Skip` method actually requires `int` argument, if you want to use `long` may requires conversion into `int` first.

Comment: is it important for you to have it as Int64? if yes then you can convert it to int. Linq accepts int as parameter

Comment: So you want to skip more then 2,147,483,647 rows?

Comment: Having a `long` version of `Skip`/`Take` means you need to have more than 2 billions rows in your table, are you sure you have that?

Comment: ``I don't get why`` - you should learn how to read errors.

Comment: @DavidG The question is why there is `LongCount` method then. It looks at least inconsistent to me.

Comment: @IvanStoev Oh yes, I agree there probably should be a `SkipLong` method, I just asked the question because I seriously doubt OP is really in need of it.

Comment: @IvanStoev Actually, thinking about this a bit more, skipping 2 billion records seems a bit smelly to me. Actually makes sense that they didn't implement it.

Comment: ^ this and not sure how this is a duplicate. See @DavidG [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32309807/how-use-long-type-for-skip-in-linq#comment78222516_32309901).

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt I've just added another comment on that post, didn't really think about it till now....

Comment: @DavidG Yeah, I don't see a practical usage for this, but who knows. The point is that the same applies to `LongCount`, so I was just wondering why they did the later. And of course if they did the later, why not did the former :) Anyway, while there is an easy "fix" for `Enumerable`, as you wrote in your comment to the "duplicate", no solution for L2E. I mean, not using `ToList`, just multiple `Queryable` `Skip`, which unfortunately are aggregated to a single int value during the SQL translation.

Comment: @alaa_sayegh, I get how impractical it might seem to skip 2billioin plus records, in this case the  method that sends the parameter is of datatype Long.